# How to use segment trees to find two smallest numbers and one maximum number in a range in an unsorted array?

Tags: arrays, segment-tree

I am currently using segment tree to find out the smallest and largest number in a range in an unsorted array by comparing and storing the smallest and largest of sub-arrays.

However, I am getting confused on what information needs to be saved while finding two smallest numbers and one largest number in a range in an unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually,
instead of storing min and max in range of a node, you can store max and array/ArrayList of minimum values.

When mergining 2 nodes:

1. Create new array/ArrayList,
2. copy both children arrays into it
3. Sort it
4. Delete elements from back till you have array with size <= 2